# how to store multiple images in a single files in database

Tags: php, mysql

i have a file created named images in database

as a field will store one value at a time

i want to store multiple images in that field

Ex : 1.jpg, 2.png, 4.jpg and so on

so is there any way to store like this through php in the database

and while retrieving the values i want that data to be in a array

like `a[0] = 1.jpg; a[1] = 2.png` and so on

Comment: show your code please

Comment: use `$images = implode(", ", $arr);` and store the `$images` to the database.

Comment: You must have to use another table for storing images.  This will help you better management of images. You can add, edit, update, delete image as easy as possible.

Comment: Take image paths into an array, iterate through loop and store them in DB.

Answer (score 1):

Create a text field in the database and set the value to json_encode ($my_array). Retrieve them with $my_array = json_decode ($sql ['image_field']);

As of MySQL 5.7.8, there is a [JSON field type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html) which you may want to look into.